# any example of rosserial_embeddedlinux over serial port?

Tags: ros, linux, embedded, rosserial

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The [examples of rosserial_embeddedlinux](http://wiki.ros.org/rosserial_embeddedlinux/Tutorials) are all about TCP connection, sometimes there're needs to communicate between ROS and an bare linux system without ROS. And it's weird when I click the FAQ it pops all 24840 questions in ROS Answer to me, So I decide to raise the 24841 one. Any help?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/221080/any-example-of-rosserial_embeddedlinux-over-serial-port?/) by [taogashi](https://answers.ros.org/users/20902/taogashi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 26 on 2015-11-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can use something like https://github.com/wjwwood/serial/.

[Here is a simple example](https://github.com/garyservin/serial-example/blob/master/src/serial_example_node.cpp) of how to use it to communicate with arduino (without using rosserial_arduino)

---

Originally posted by [Gary Servin](https://answers.ros.org/users/10481/gary-servin/) with karma: 962 on 2015-11-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [taogashi](https://answers.ros.org/users/20902/taogashi/) on 2015-11-21**:
Thanks for your answer. However I prefer rosserial because I suppose it not only perform transparent transmission but also some protocol to ensure reliable communication.